# Preserve a string union and string type to display hints

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Sometimes I want typescript to show me hints and not to throw an Error on any mistyping.
I came to this problem and solved it, yet I don't understand how.

Pay attention to this line:

```js
constructor(public name: ExceptionName | (String & string), message?: string) {
```

In the following code, (ignore Localization and LangName):

```js
function requireLangFile(lang: LangName) {
  if (Localization.path) {
    try {
      const file = lang + ".json"
      return require(Localization.path + "/" + file)
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof Error) {
        throw new Exception("TranslationError", "cannot require lang file")
      }
    }
  }

  throw new Exception("TranslationError1", "Empty path")
}

type ExceptionName = "TranslationError"
class Exception extends Error {
  constructor(public name: ExceptionName | (String & string), message?: string) {
    super(message)
  }
}
```

This code (typescript 4.4.0-dev)

- Doesn't throw any errors
- Passes any string for name in constructor
- Even though there is a hint with "TranslationError"

[How it looks in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTvwH.png)

However, if I decide to remove *string* type, it will throw error.
If I decide to remove *String*, it will not display a hint.

Without *string* no errors, but there is a
[hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox0sA.png)
with "TranslationError"

Without *String* will throw
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEdr0.png)

```
Class 'Exception' incorrectly extends base class 'Error'.
  Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
    Type 'String | "TranslationError"' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'String' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        'string' is a primitive, but 'String' is a wrapper object. Prefer using 'string' when possible.ts(2415)
```

But with all together, there will not be any errors and will work as intended, displaying hints, passing any string.

Questions:

1. Why does it work?
2. How does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type `ExceptionName` admits only valid exception names, and would thus error on invalid ones.

The type `ExceptionName | string` admits valid exception names, or any string, and thus displays a hint offering valid exception names, or any previously used strings, but never showing an error.

The type `String & string` admits any value that is both a `string` and a `String`. Strictly speaking, there is no such value, since EcmaScript treats these as distinct types. To wit, `typeof` is required to return a different value:

```
typeof "hello" === "string"
typeof new String("hello") === "object"
```

However, since EcmaScript will implicitly convert a `string` into a `String` upon the slightest provocation, the TypeScript team chose to treat a `string` like a `String` in some cases.

In particular, it is legal to pass a `string` to a function that expects a `String`, because as soon as that function uses the value in a way specific to `String` (such as invoking a method on it), EcmaScript will implicitly convert the `string` to a `String`, without the function ever noticing that it has, in fact, received a `string` rather than a `String`.

However, as the `typeof` example shows, the function might notice a difference, and for some functions, that difference might matter. TypeScript therefore doesn't treat `string` and `String` as equivalent types everywhere.

This inconsistency in the type system is why your code exhibits such surprising behavior. In displaying type hints, TypeScript treats `string` and `String` as different types, and therefore finds no values to suggest for `string & String`, and therefore only suggests values from `ExceptionName` for `ExceptionName | (string & String)`.

In contrast, when actually passing a `string` to the method, typescript checks whether the value is assignable to `ExceptionName` (it isn't), or assignable to `string` (it is) and assignable to `String` (it is, due to the special rule it mentioned above), and therefore finds the string assignable to `ExceptionName | (string & String)`, displaying no error.

That explains why and how your code behaves as it does.

However, before you use this trick all over your code base, I should warn you that you are relying on undocumented behavior, and that this inconsistency might be removed in a future version of typescript. After all, that hints and type checking disagree on which values may be passed to a function might rightfully be called a compiler bug.